# Python - Extract everything in a filepath, after a certain directory

Tags: python

Let's say I have a folder like this.

```
/home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder
```

Everything after the media directory should be kept. The remaining should be removed.

```
/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder
```

I was originally doing it this way but as more subdirectories were added to different folders started generating invalid filepaths

```
split_absolute = [os.sep.join(os.path.normpath(y).split(os.sep)[-2:]) for y in absolute_path]
```

The problem this causes is that once you start going deeper, the media path is cut out of the filepath all together.

So if I went into

```
media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder/
```

The filepath now becomes this, when it needs to include everything up to /media.

```
/images/02_car_folder
```

What are some ways to actually handle this? I won't know users filepaths will be leading up to media, but I know that everything after media is what should be kept regardless, no matter how deep their folders go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want quite easily using [`Path.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = "/home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder"
parts = Path(path).parts
stripped_path = Path(*parts[parts.index("media"):])
```

Result:

```py
>>> print(stripped_path)
media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder
```

Comment: I was going for something like `print(a.split('/', maxsplit=5))` which would give `['', 'home', 'user', 'dev', 'Project', 'media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder']`, last element being what is needed, but your solution is much more elegant

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan In general, don't process paths using string operations. `os.path` and `pathlib` exist for a reason. Your solution (even if we assume we always wanted to split on the 5th component) doesn't work on Windows for example, since it uses backslashes.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you @orlp

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this library existed. Amazing solution to the problem, thank you.

Comment: @orlp late for a comeback, but `os.path.sep` might make my solution better, work for all os'es. Yours is still better though @orlp

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to use some path specific libraries.
Just work with strings:

*※ note → the weak point of working with paths as strings is that you need to handle many edge cases by yourself (for example if path will be `media/blahblah/blahblah2` or `/blahblah/blahblah2/media`). [`pathlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70192959/13946204) solving these cases out of the box.*

```py
import os

full_path1 = "/home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder"
full_path2 = "/home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/media/images/02_car_folder"

separator_dir = os.path.sep + "media" + os.path.sep

print(f'Separate by {separator_dir}')

if separator_dir in full_path1:
  separated_path1 = os.path.sep + separator_dir.join(full_path1.split(separator_dir)[1:])
else:
  separated_path1 = full_path1
if separator_dir in full_path2:
  separated_path2 = os.path.sep + separator_dir.join(full_path2.split(separator_dir)[1:])
else:
  separated_path2 = full_path2

print(f'Full path 1 is {full_path1}')
print(f'Full path 2 is {full_path2}')
print(f'Separated path 1 is {separated_path1}')
print(f'Separated path 2 is {separated_path2}')
```

First path has one media folder
Second path has two media folders, but use only first for path cutting

```
Separate by /media/
Full path 1 is /home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder
Full path 2 is /home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/media/images/02_car_folder
Separated path 1 is /image_dump/images/02_car_folder
Separated path 2 is /image_dump/media/images/02_car_folder
```

Comment: `pathlib` is part of the standard  library as much as `os` is. This is super fragile.

Comment: @orlp Yep. using of `pathlib` is a good solution. My answer is one of many ways how to solve the problem. Please can you point theoretical `super fragile` example for my solution? That will be useful comment.

Comment: Your code fails for `/home/user/dev/Project/media` for example, where it should produce `media`, instead it leaves it unchanged. There's like a billion of these edge cases, which is why I said this approach is fragile.

Comment: @orlp yep. good point. I updated my post

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regex, concise and easy:

```
path = '/home/user/dev/Project/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder'
import re
re.search('/media/.*', path).group(0)
```

Output: `'/media/image_dump/images/02_car_folder'`

If the presence of media is unsure:

```
m = re.search('/media/.*', path)
m.group(0) if m else None # or any default you want
```

If you want the first `/` to be optional if media is at the beginning, use `'(?:/|^)media/.*'`

Comment: Just a very small note, but `m.group(0) if m else path` looking better. It's time to fight with PHP-like behaviour when most of exceptions or non planned actions returning `None` :)

Comment: I am shocked you compare my code to PHP  I added a note on the default value, I didn't want to include the initial path as it might not be more meaningful ;)